# How to configure vimspector.json to work with poetry run

Tags: python, python-poetry, vimspector

I'm building a CLI in python using poetry and have used vimspector separately in the past for python debugging.

When I test a normal python file, I can set up my vimspector.json like

```
{
  "configurations": {
    "run": {
      "adapter": "debugpy",
      "configuration": {
        "request": "launch",
        "protocol": "auto",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/gzrparse.py",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
      }
    },
    "parse": {
      "adapter": "debugpy",
      "configuration": {
        "request": "launch",
        "protocol": "auto",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/test/parse.py",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which works fine for those purposes, I would love to debug my CLI with vimspector as well, but i'm struggling to find the correct configurations in my .json file. When on the CLI I can `poetry run packagename` which works fine, so i'm trying to get vimspector to replicate that command.

Does anyone know if that's possible? Or how to do it?
I've been trying to adapt from [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/34751/use-poetry-shell-in-vimspector) but I'm a little out of my depth on what i'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to execute `poetry install` to create virtualenv and install your module in it.

Then you can start debugging a file you are editing using the configuration:

```
        "run-current-file": {
        "adapter": "debugpy",
        "variables": {
            "venv": {
                "shell": ["poetry", "env", "info", "-p"]
            }
        },

        "configuration": {
            "request": "launch",
            "protocol": "auto",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "python": "${venv}/bin/python",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    },
```

This will start debugging the currently open file using python from poetry virtual environment found by executing command `poetry env info -p`

Of course you can leave the "program" setting to always debug the same file:

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/test/parse.py"
```

To debug a module (provided your module has `__main__.py` file) you need configuration:

```
"runmodule": {
    "adapter": "debugpy",
    "variables": {
        "venv": {
            "shell": ["poetry", "env", "info", "-p"]
        }
    },

    "configuration": {
        "request": "launch",
        "protocol": "auto",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "python": "${venv}/bin/python",
        "module": "<mymodule>",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
    }
},
```

Where have to replace `<mymodule>` with your module name.